# Is generating a Turing Machine that output a given string $s$ in NP?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

I believe the problem stated in title is in P because I can just hardcode $s$ into $<M>$, such that $M()=s$.

However, my real question is, if I want to ensure that the generated $<M>$ is the shortest, is this problem in NP, or even computable?

Formally, define $f: \{0,1\}^*\rightarrow\{0,1\}^*, f(s) = <M>, s.t\quad M()=s \wedge \forall <M'> \in \{0,1\}^{i}, \forall i \in \{1,2,...,|<M>|-1\} , M'()\neq s$.

Edit:

It seems the problem I proposed above is not computable.

What if I add a constraint that the the outputted $M$ must be terminated in $T(|s|) = c_1 |s|^{c_2}+c_3$ steps, where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are predefined constants.

This problem must be in NP because a NTM could just keep constructing $<M>$ and test it for $T(|s|)$ steps, but is this problem in P?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: Since there are 5-state Turing machines (2-symbol tape) for which it is unknown whether they halt, their output if they do happen to halt is definitely unknown. Maybe it just so happens to be $s$?

Comment: Unknown or undecidable, @Arthur ?

Comment: @Arthur : Currently, there are 28 *5*-state TM's with unresolved halting property.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I personally believe it is decidable. 5 states probably isn't enough to reach the hypothesis of Gödel's incompleteness theorems or anything like that. It is known that [8000-state is undecidable](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725), and the true bound might be a bit lower than that, but I think 5 is too low to be undecidable. Whether humanity will ever know is a different question altogether.

Comment: @EricTowers Is that an official list ? Other sources speak of about $40$ open machines.

Comment: For $7$ states, the situation seems to be utterly hopeless. $5$ could be solved , but is already extremely difficult and $6$ is widely believed to be infeasible. Considering Arthur's comment, the given problem should be undecideable.

Comment: @Peter : [Skelet's list](http://skelet.ludost.net/bb/nreg.html) leaves 42 unresolved by a prior version of his software.  But 14 of these have been resolved by others.

Comment: I heard of a $43$ th machine that was missed. What about that ? Additionally, I couldn't find anywhere the current status : all the unknown machines, number of steps they run at least etc. Does anyone have a reference ?

Comment: What is meant with the "shortest" turing machine ?

Comment: @Peter given a encoding scheme of any TM, the shortest TM meaning that there is no TM has shorter encoding result can solve this problem.

Comment: This leads to an amusing paradox, related to the language paradox: "The smallest natural number $n$ which can be uniquely described in less than 100 characters." Basically, if we could write an algorithm to solve your question, we could construct a program like this sentence, and we'd have a contradiction.